# React apollo multiple query in redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, graphql, apollo

When I'm trying to do two different query I get this error how do I fix it

``Error: query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in the query option.

Here's a snippet of the code

```
//in my index class I dispatch some actions

componentDidMount () {
 this.props.fetchNavigationBarDataThunk();
 this.props.fetchActionToDoTitleDataThunk();
} 

//then in my action I have something like that 

import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const opts = {uri: 'http://localhost:8080/wfgen/graphql'};
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface(opts);
const client = new ApolloClient({networkInterface});

var query1 = gql`query {...}`;

var query2= gql`query {...}`;


export function fetchActionToDoTitleDataThunk () {
return (dispatch) => {
dispatch(fetchActionToDoTitleData())
client.query({ query2 }).then((results) => {
  if (results.networkStatus === 7 && results.loading === false) {
    dispatch(fetchActionToDoTitleDataFulFilled(results));
  }
  else{
  ...


export function fetchNavigationBarDataThunk () {
return (dispatch) => {

dispatch(fetchNavigationBarData())
client.query({query}).then((results) => {
  if (results.networkStatus === 7 && results.loading === false) {
    dispatch(fetchNavigationBarDataFulFilled(results));
  }
  else{
 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* your issue here is with this `client.query({ query2 })` and `client.query({query})`

first, using shorthand object property initialization, `{ query2 }` is equivalent to `{ query2: query2 }` - but ApolloClient expects something like `{ query: query2 }`.

second, based off the code that you've provided, `query` is undefined. I think you mean either `client.query({query: query1})` or `client.query({query: query2})`

Comment: i just wanted to keep the code short so I didn't write the full query but thanks for the help